# Network HTTP traffic logging using windows server and mikrotik router

Tags: networking, http, proxy, logging, windows-server

there

I would like to know how to be able to forward all the http (possibly https) traffic from a network running through a mikrotik router to a windows server where is to received and a report is created displaying sites visited for example.

Please explain both sides (forwarding the traffic with web proxy and also receiving the logs and reporting on it).

I do not have a lot of experience in this regard so please bear that in mind when answering.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If your router supports `syslogging` then you can turn this on and point it to a syslog server of some sort where it can store the accessed URLs into a [preferably] database system that you can then report on. Depending on how the syslog can be configured it can log all your Internet-bound requests.